# How to make columns align horizontally OR vertically dependent on viewport in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a following setup -

```css
.left {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #208ea3;
}

.right {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #37a862;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" color="green">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-start">

    <div class="col-lg-3 left d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="first-section">
      <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row-fluid align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
          <div class="col-xl-6" id="dynamic-columns">
              some quotations
          </div>

          <div class="col-xl-6" id="dynamic-columns">
            <h3>title</h3>
              Some text  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9 right" id="next-section">
      more text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to assign properties to `#dynamic-columns` such that when the screen has a `max-height` of 500px, the columns take 100% of the height and arrange themselves side by side. As of now, this horizontal alignment doesn't take place and the bottom `#dynamic-columns` is hidden by `#next-section` if there is more text to it.

My requirement comes from the fact that many phones have around 500px of height in landscape mode, which doesn't let me show the content in `#first-section` vertically. Thus, I will like to align them horizontally so that first `#dynamic-columns` is on the left of the screen and the second on the right.

I figured that the following query will be necessary, but I am not able to find the properties -

```css
@include (max-height:500px) {
  #dynamic-columns {
      display: ??
    }
    
}
```

Comment: again irrelevant duplicates, reading half the title this time ...

Comment: for the newbies, it is very tough to search for the correct terms to find these type of questions... thanks for the answer! it works

Comment: these questions are completely irrelevant to your question don't worry ;) .It will get reopened soon (you can read them all, you won't find any hint for a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below. I update the bootstrap verstion to 4.5 to be able to use `vh-100`

```css
.left {
  background-color: #208ea3;
}

.right {
  background-color: #37a862;
}

@media (max-height:500px) {
  .left > div {
      height:100%;
      width:50%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" color="green">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 vh-100 left d-flex flex-column flex-wrap justify-content-center text-center" id="first-section">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        some quotations
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <h3>title</h3>
        Some text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 vh-100 right" id="next-section">
      more text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to achieve what you're looking for in pure CSS as well. I hope it helps. One thing I found was that you were using @include instead of @media.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: white;
}

.column-1 {
  background: teal;
}

.column-2 {
  background: blue;
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column-2">Column 1</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Indeed, OP is probably using SCSS which is what the `@include` keyword is from.